# Upgrade from Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 to 16.10 wants to remove Calibre

Tags: upgrade

I tried to upgrade Ubuntu Gnome from 16.04 to 16.10. In the list of packages to be removed, I was surprised to find Calibre. I canceled the upgrade and tried to find why this was happening.

The installed version is the latest available from the getdeb repository (v2.82).

I do not understand why calibre has to be removed and I do not recall ever having any one application suggested for removal during a distro upgrade.

I am just mentioning that another package (Gambas3) has stopped updating in a while (installed is v3.5.4, available in repository is 3.8.4). I don´t know if this is related or shows that something is broken in my system.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are changing your apt source for the getdeb calibre repository from "xenial" to "yakkety" at the same time.  do-release-upgrade may not do this, or may disable it, depending on how you are planning to upgrade.

Most likely the existing version installed depends on something not available in 16.10, but if it can find the upgraded package from getdeb for yakkety hopefully it will be OK.

Worst case you can most likely re-install it after upgrade.