# Upgrading from Ubuntu to Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: gnome, upgrade, ubuntu-gnome

The computer lab in my college uses Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Since I'm the only one in my class who knows how to use Ubuntu, I'm allowed to do what I want on the computers. I have a pendrive with Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 on it. I tried installing it on the computer, and there was an option that said something like upgrade to GNOME 16.10. My question is, if I do that, will the apps already installed get deleted? Or will they remain?

Answer (score 3):

The installed apps probably will not be affected terribly, *but* as a normal upgrade, you should disable/remove any third party PPAs, adding them back after the upgrade, and remove any proprietary video drivers before doing the upgrade.  And always make backups of essential, important or interesting data...

Additionally, Ubuntu-gnome 16.10 is very near end-of-life.  You should chose either the 16.04 LTS, or 17.04 for the upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

A Ubuntu upgrade should not remove any previously installed apps except in rare circumstances where that app is no longer supported in the new distro.  I've been running Ubuntu for quite a while and for the most part, upgrades have been fairly painless.

You can run into issues such as this one though.  [Upgrade from Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 to 16.10 wants to remove Calibre](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902965/upgrade-from-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-to-16-10-wants-to-remove-calibre)